# How to get data from anonymous list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have anonymous type list. I want to get data from this list

My code is as bellow

```
 var data = from EP in DbContext.EmployeeProfesionalDtls
                       join DM in DbContext.DesignationMasters on EP.DesigId equals DM.DesigId
                       join DP in DbContext.DepartmentMasters on new { DepId = EP.DepId } equals new { DepId = DP.DeptId }
                       select new
                       {
                           ProfId = EP.ProfId,
                           EmpId = EP.EmpId,
                           EntryDate = DM.EntryDate,
                           DeptName = DP.DeptName,
                           DepartmentUnitID = DP.UnitId,
                           DepartmentEntryDate = DP.EntryDate
                       }
```

"data" have anonymous type list. I wants to get data from this anonymous type list.

Comment: I have to display data in View

Comment: Then create a view model containing those properties and project into that rather than an anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a view model i.e. a class to send it to view :

```
var data = from EP in DbContext.EmployeeProfesionalDtls
                   join DM in DbContext.DesignationMasters on EP.DesigId equals DM.DesigId
                   join DP in DbContext.DepartmentMasters on new { DepId = EP.DepId } equals new { DepId = DP.DeptId }
                   select new Test()
                   {
                       ProfId = EP.ProfId,
                       EmpId = EP.EmpId,
                       EntryDate = DM.EntryDate,
                       DeptName = DP.DeptName,
                       DepartmentUnitID = DP.UnitId,
                       DepartmentEntryDate = DP.EntryDate
                   }
```

where Test is a class with these properties.